# Targeting specific menu with wp_nav_menu_items

Tags: functions

Hey! I have added a wp_loginout() to my header using a snippet in my functions.php:

```
    add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2);
function add_login_logout_link($items, $args) {

        ob_start();
        wp_loginout('index.php');
        $loginoutlink = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        $items .= '<li>'. $loginoutlink .'</li>';

    return $items;
}
```

The thing is that it shows the login link in every one of my three menues:

```
    function register_main_menus() {
   register_nav_menus(
      array(
         'primary-menu' => __( 'Primary Menu' ),
         'secondary-menu' => __( 'Secondary Menu' ),
         'footer-menu' => __( 'Footer Menu' ),
      )
   );
};
```

I would like to target the wp_nav_menu_items filter to only include the login link in the primary menu. Ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See this [related question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2143/customizing-only-a-specific-menu-using-the-wp-nav-menu-items-hook). I guess in your case you'd wrap your code in `if( $args->theme_location == 'primary-menu' )`.

Answer (score 2):

Please modify your code with the following code
You forgot to add condition `if ($args->theme_location == 'primary-menu')` this condition check if menu is primary menu or not.

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2);
function add_login_logout_link($items, $args) {
    if ($args->theme_location == 'primary-menu') {
        ob_start();
        wp_loginout('index.php');
        $loginoutlink = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        $items .= '<li>' . $loginoutlink . '</li>';
        return $items;
    }
}

function register_main_menus() {
   register_nav_menus(
      array(
         'primary-menu' => __( 'Primary Menu' ),
         'secondary-menu' => __( 'Secondary Menu' ),
         'footer-menu' => __( 'Footer Menu' ),
      )
   );
};
```

Comment: You should explain the code with words, so that others understand the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I am fairly new to WordPress development, and am trying to fully understand the documentation.
I find that there are so many ways to skin a cat, and some are a lot more complicated than others.
in the case of the above, the probem is solved much easier than previous described;

```php
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2);
```

the wp_nav_menu_items hook is actually dynamic and you can simply add in between wp_nav_menu__items to target the specific menu.
example;

```php
add_filter('wp_nav_primary-menu_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2);
```

if you inspect the  wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php  you can verify this fact.