# Adding custom text in items titles from wp_nav_menu()

Tags: menus, hooks

I need to add something after each title of a specific menu called by wp_nav_menu()

I tried

```
add_filter('wp_nav_title', 'testing_stuff');
```

with

```
function testing_stuff() {
$item->title = $item->title . ' testing';
return $item->title;
```

}

without any success, i'm not familiar enough with hooking.

My purpose :

- when I called menu ID = 4;
- for each title of each item
- i pull out data from current page meta with $meta_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $meta_key, true );
- I add this data after the anchor text in a

So every item of the menu will have a specific data added to its content, data I could manipulate from custom field.

I would appreciate any clue that get me on the right path.

Thank you.

Comment: `wp_nav_manu` comes with options to allow you append/preprend text onto the links - is there a particular reason why you can't use them?

Comment: Yes, the reason is that I have to get the value of the metadata key 'packaging' from each item, and I couldn't run a function from wp_nav_menu (correct me if i'm wrong)

Comment: Simon - add this as a separate answer, and feel free to accept it. It'll make it more obvious for others who have a similar question.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I did as you said, for others to pick it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works, but with the following caveats. It will **run for every menu**, but it will **not run for `wp_page_menu`**, a usuall default callback if a menu can't be found.

Finally, menu items aren't necessary pages - so you may want to do some logic to check that the menu item you are dealing with is a page/post from which you want to obtain the metadata.

Here's the code:

```
add_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item','my_item_setup' );
function my_item_setup($item) {
    //Use the following to conduct logic;
    $object_id = (int) $item->object_id; //object ID.
    $object_type = $item->type; //E.g. 'post_type'
    $object_type_label = $item->type_label; //E.g. 'post' or 'page';

    //You could, optionally add classes to the menu item.
    $item_class = $item->classes;

    //Make sure $item_class is an array.
    //Alter the class:
    $item->classes= $item_class;

    //Alter the title:
    $pack_meta_value = get_post_meta($object_id, 'test', true );
     if($pack_meta_value ){
         $item->title = $item->title.'<span>' . $pack_meta_value . '</span>'; 
     }

    return $item;
}
```

I would be interested to see if there was a better way of doing this, preferably a method which allowed you to check for which menu these items are for...

---

I've moved this from the comments. If you wish to restrict this function to a particular menu, you could **try** the following. *This has not been tested*.

First remove the `add_filter` from the code above. Instead insert into a function which is added onto an earlier hook, and conditionally adds the filter (say when the menu is 'primary'):

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args','add_my_setup_function' );
    function add_my_setup_function($args) {
        if( $args['theme_location'] == 'primary' ):
         add_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item','my_item_setup' );
        endif;      
        return $args;
    }
```

Finally remove the filter, once the items have been loaded, so that it isn't called for secondary menus:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','remove_my_setup_function', 10, 2);
function remove_my_setup_function( $nav, $args ) {
   remove_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item', 'my_item_setup' );
    return $nav;
}
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, thank you ;
That's very close but not quite : the $item->ID is not ID of the page, but ID of the item menu [nav_menu_item] ; and cannot be used to get meta data.

The method is allright, but either we're starting at the wrong hook (wp_setup_nav_menu_item) or I will need to find the ID of the post using the permalink (which is the right one in the object $item.

Comment: Sorry, try object_id instead :D

Comment: This is how I finally got it : damn, where do I put that code ? (the ID of the post each item refers to isn't part of the $item object. Should be somewhere in the $nav object maybe ; and the ID of the menu is in the $args object. So to create a filter that only works in a specific menu the hook must be placed in another place. See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2143/customizing-only-a-specific-menu-using-the-wp-nav-menu-items-hook

Comment: See my comment above. As for the other hook you mentioned - that was the obvious one, but it filters the html of the menu, so it's not the easiest to add classes into.

Comment: I will add the answer to you, as your code was the starting point of my solution, but do I need to create another answer to place the working code ? (object_id wasn't working either, I checked to whole object with print_r to see is there was any reference to the ID of the post. There isn't).

Comment: Simon, object_id worked for me (it referenced the ID of the page) - did you make sure object_id was an integer rather than a string representation before passing to `get_post_meta`?

Comment: Stephen, yes, i checked the value of object_id (by displaying it) vs value of the ID of the targeted page and it was never the same, for any item or menu.

Comment: The line `remove_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item', 'remove_my_setup__function' );` should be `remove_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item', 'my_item_setup' );` instead. Otherwise, a very good example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Stephen : this is the working form of the code (i removed options I don't use from original proposition). I just test if there is non-empty value to meta value so I don't spread empty  to the html.

```
function packaging_setup($item) {
//Alter the title:
$ala_page = get_page_by_title( $item->title ); // getting the page itself
$ala_page_id = $ala_page->ID; // the page ID the item is refering to
$pack_meta_key = 'box_packaging_meta'; // my meta key
$pack_meta_value = get_post_meta($ala_page_id, $pack_meta_key, true ); // getting data
    if (!empty($pack_meta_value)) { //so I do not add empty spans
    $item->title = $item->title.'<span>' . $pack_meta_value . '</span>'; //altering
    }
    return $item; 
}

add_filter('wp_setup_nav_menu_item', 'packaging_setup');
```